# QT Rotating object problems

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I am currently working on a project that has a spinning object. The object's rotation speed is changed and its direction of rotation is changed (forwards/backward). After doing some research I came across `RotationAnimator` on the [QT documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rotationanimator.html), it seems to have everything I need and I can easily reverse direction. The only problem is that is in QML. My program is entirely in Qt's C++.

I tried an attempt at using `QVariantAnimation` (documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html))but every way I have tried there is always some problem. Changing speed is relatively easy, just `fooAnimation->setLoop(-1)` (loop indefinitely) and change the duration of the animation. The problem I run into is looping forwards AND backward. Or in other terms, changing direction. I have attempted to change the direction of the animation using `fooAnimation->setDirection(<Direction goes here>)`, but **if I run the animation in reverse long enough it will stop the animation entirely. It will only loop forwards.** That's the key part of the problem.

So I tried alternative ways to change the direction. One idea was changing the `endValue` from 360 degrees to -360 using `fooAnimation->setEndValue(<value goes here>)` when I want to reverse, but this has an adverse effect. If I were to swap the direction, the current rotation: let's say it's 110, will be inverted. So now it suddenly jumps to -110 and starts from there. This leads to very jittery rotation as every time a direction swap happens it teleports the rotation of the object.

This seems like a pretty simple thing to implement, rotating an object that can have its rotation speed and direction changed,  but I just can't wrap my head around how I could implement it with animations.

A side note here is that all this is being done in **Qt 3D** so I can grab rotation and other properties from the rotating object (or in this case its `QTransform`)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this effect. On this Qt/QML demo, I used an approach based on `NumberAnimation` to rotate the cube.

These are the key ideas behind it:

- The cube has a `Transform` component that defines the 4x4 matrix that Qt3D uses to place the cube in the world using predefined rotation and scale values. The `NumberAnimation` simply changes the rotation angle used on this transform to make the cube rotate on the screen;
- The rotation speed is defined by the `duration` property of that `NumberAnimation`: a smaller value makes the cube rotate faster. The cube takes 5 seconds to rotate from 0 to 360 degrees;
- Changing the rotation speed means recalculating the `duration` of the animation based on how far away from 0 degrees the current rotation angle is. The animation needs to be restarted whenever we change ANY `NumberAnimation` properties;
- When the direction of the rotation is changed, we store the current rotation angle in `cubeTransform.startAngle` and update the `to` and `from` properties of `NumberAnimation` along with `duration` so the cube can be rotated in a new direction starting from the current angle.

I added a few buttons to the UI to change the direction and speed in runtime:

[image]

**main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.12 as QQ2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.12

import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0
import Qt3D.Logic 2.0

QQ2.Item {
    id: windowId
    width: 800
    height: 800

    property real cubeScale: 100.0
    property int rotationSpeed: 5000
    property real speedFactor: 1.0
    property bool clockwiseRotation: true

    Scene3D {
        id: scene3D
        anchors.fill: parent
        aspects: ["input", "logic"]
        focus: true
        cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio

        Entity {
            id: rootEntity

            Camera {
                id: camera
                projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                fieldOfView: 45
                nearPlane : 0.1
                farPlane : 100000.0
                position: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 500.0)
                viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
                upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
            }

            components: [
                RenderSettings {
                    activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                        camera: camera
                        clearColor: "silver"
                    }
                },
                InputSettings { }
            ]

            Entity {
                id: lightEntity
                enabled: true

                DirectionalLight {
                    id: infiniteLight
                    color: "white"
                    intensity: 1.0
                    worldDirection: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
                }

                Transform {
                    id: infiniteLightTransform
                    translation: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 500.0)
                }

                components: [ infiniteLight, infiniteLightTransform ]
            }

            Entity {
                id: cubeEntity

                CuboidMesh {
                    id: cubeMesh
                }

                PhongMaterial {
                    id: cubeMaterial
                    ambient: "red"
                    diffuse: Qt.rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                }

                Transform {
                    id: cubeTransform

                    property real angle: 0.0
                    property real startAngle: 0.0

                    matrix: {
                        var m = Qt.matrix4x4();
                        m.rotate(cubeTransform.angle, Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0));
                        m.translate(Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0));
                        m.scale(windowId.cubeScale, windowId.cubeScale, windowId.cubeScale);
                        return m;
                    }
                }

                components: [ cubeMesh, cubeMaterial, cubeTransform ]
            }

            QQ2.NumberAnimation {
                id: cubeAnimation

                property int startPos: {
                    if (cubeTransform.startAngle === 0)
                    {
                        if (windowId.clockwiseRotation === true)
                            return 0;

                        return 360;
                    }

                    return cubeTransform.startAngle;
                }

                property int endPos: (windowId.clockwiseRotation === true) ? 360 : 0

                target: cubeTransform
                property: "angle"
                duration: windowId.rotationSpeed / windowId.speedFactor
                from: cubeAnimation.startPos
                to: cubeAnimation.endPos
                loops: 1
                running: true

                onStarted: {
                    console.log("onStarted");
                }

                onFinished: {
                    console.log("onFinished");
                    // reset the starting angle
                    cubeTransform.startAngle = 0;

                    // reset the duration of the animation
                    cubeAnimation.duration = windowId.rotationSpeed / windowId.speedFactor;

                    // the animation is currently stopped, run it again
                    cubeAnimation.running = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    QQ2.Row {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            text: "Change Direction"

            onClicked: {
                // pause the animation
                cubeAnimation.pause();

                // invert rotation
                windowId.clockwiseRotation = !windowId.clockwiseRotation;

                // store current angle as the starting angle for the rotation
                cubeTransform.startAngle = cubeTransform.angle;

                // update the remaining time to avoid changing the rotation speed
                let progressPercentage = cubeTransform.startAngle / 360.0;
                if (windowId.clockwiseRotation)
                    progressPercentage = 1.0 - progressPercentage;

                cubeAnimation.duration = (windowId.rotationSpeed / windowId.speedFactor) * progressPercentage;

                // restart the animation from this angle using a new direction
                cubeAnimation.restart();
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "1x"
            highlighted: (windowId.speedFactor === 1.0)

            onClicked: changeSpeed(1.0)
        }

        Button {
            text: "2x"
            highlighted: (windowId.speedFactor === 2.0)

            onClicked: changeSpeed(2.0)
        }
    }

    function changeSpeed(newSpeed) {
        windowId.speedFactor = newSpeed;

        // pause the animation
        cubeAnimation.pause();

        // store current angle as the starting angle for the rotation
        cubeTransform.startAngle = cubeTransform.angle;

        // update the remaining time to avoid changing the rotation speed
        let progressPercentage = cubeTransform.startAngle / 360.0;
        if (windowId.clockwiseRotation)
            progressPercentage = 1.0 - progressPercentage;

        cubeAnimation.duration = (windowId.rotationSpeed / windowId.speedFactor) * progressPercentage;

        // restart the animation from this angle using a new direction
        cubeAnimation.restart();
    }
}
```